# What is the advantage of 'register_block_type' (the PHP function) when creating custom blocks?

Tags: block-editor

I am currently registering custom blocks via javascript only. I am building a site with lots of custom layouts and widgets, and I'm using the [new custom blocks of Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/) to facilitate content creation using these custom layouts.

I have a few Custom Blocks, but I did not want to create a Plugin for each block, so I decided to group all the blocks together inside my theme. I created directory for each block, and each directory has an block.js file, which registers the block via the javascript function `wp.blocks.registerBlockType`.

**Sample block.js**

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
registerBlockType( 'myguten/test-block', {
    title: 'Basic Example',
    icon: 'smiley',
    category: 'layout',
    edit() {
        return <div>Hola, mundo!</div>;
    },
    save() {
        return <div>Hola, mundo!</div>;
    },
} );
```

Here is the sample folder structure for my blocks:

```
 /my-theme
    /src
        /blocks
            /a-custom-block
                block.js
                styles.scss
            /another-custom-block
                block.js
                styles.scss
      index.js
  functions.php
  webpack.config.js
```

I have webpack configured to bundle all my `block.js` files into one file called `dist/blocks.build.js`. And in my functions.php, I load my `blocks.build` like so:

```
function enqueue_custom_blocks() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_blocks', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/blocks.js', array('wp-blocks'));

}

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'enqueue_custom_blocks');
```

This setup totally works. I am able to work on my custom blocks right in my theme folder, and I have no problem using these custom blocks on my pages and posts.

Therefore, I am curious, what is the purpose of the [php function `register_block_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_type/)? Furthermore, is there anyway I could use `register_block_type` to register blocks in bulk? My only real reason for wanting to use `register_block_type` is to leverage the `render_callback` option if, for example, [my block needed to be dynamic and leverage server-side rendering. Can I apply a filter to a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.: The register_block_type lets you load additional stylesheets and scripts for your block in the frontend

2.: As you yourself wrote, register_block_type lets you define a dynamic php render_callback function

3.: If you use a render_callback, you can of course use filters within it.

EDIT: As the comments pointed out, there is some clarification needed on how to use custom filters

Firstly, you can make the whole function pluggable just by wrapping it into a function_exists like this

```
...
'render_callback' => 'my_awesome_block_render'));

if(!function_exists('my_awesome_block_render')){
  function my_awesome_block_render($attributes,$context){
      //whatever
  }
}
```

Secondly: Filters.

Wordpress filters are an interesting thing. The long and short is the following: Whenever you call `$var =apply_filters('my_cool_filter_name',$var);`, Wordpress looks into its global filter function array if a function is registered for the filter "my_cool_filter_name". So for using a custom filter, you just think of a name that hopefully isn't taken by any other plugin/function and apply_filters to it.

So, to use filters to change some aspects of your blocks render, you just use apply_filters with whatever you wish. Let's have an example with a slider block:

function my_awesome_slider_block_render_function($attributes){
  //do whatever stuff you want
  $slider_speed = apply_filters('my_awesome_slider_block_slider_speed',$attributes['slider_speed']);
  //whatever else
}

if nobody added a filter to "my_awesome_slider_block_slider_speed", the variable $slider_speed contains now $attributes['slider_speed'].

However, if for some reason you need to change this speed, (let's say, you use a child theme for mobile devices and the slider should be slower on mobile devices), you can just add a filter in your functions.php like this:

```
add_filter('my_awesome_slider_block_slider_speed','change_the_mobile_speed');
function change_the_mobile_speed($slider_speed){
  return 800;
}
```

The same works for actions, too.

Happy Coding!

Comment: What are exactly those filters? I found [this demo](https://github.com/bigbite/gutenberg-postlist-demo) which is helping me understand the inner workings of custom blocks. He is using a filter, ie: `add_filter( 'gutenberg_post_list_render_filter', 'render_guten_post_list_filter', 10, 2 );` I don't understand how he came up with the name of that hook. Nonetheless, this explanation is helpful in understanding the role of `register_block_types`

Comment: @JeffWilkerson that is a custom filter he is using for that plugin, you can see it applied using `apply_filters( 'gutenberg_post_list_render_filter'`... in the *render.php* file. I'm also interested in knowing what is @kuchenundkakao meaning in point 3.

Comment: @Alvaro Yes I know that is a custom function, I am curious how he registers the filter. Obviously, Wordpress is sniffing for filters named {my_cool_block}_render_filter, and calling it if the function exists. I've seen this type of thing before, where you can hook into some functionality by just suffixing your function with a common identifier. I just don't know how he came up with that exact name. I don't see the key 'gutenberg-post-list' being defined anywhere.

Comment: On second thought, I see comments in the repo that the demo no longer works. So it seems that there is not a filter that I can tap into on the fly, and the only way I can control whats rendered is to leverage the `render_callback` option when registering the block

Comment: I edited the answer and i hope this clarifies the usage of filters ;)

Comment: Thank you @kuchenundkakao for clarifying. This is a good solution for  blocks that I make... If anyone is looking for a blanket filter for all blocks, I have found a filter called `render_block` as seen in `/wp-includes/blocks,php`, in the `render_block` function. Here is an example of using that filter: 
`function test_filter($block_content, $block) {
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r(array('FILTER:', $block_content, $block));
 echo '</pre>';
 return $block_content;
}

add_filter('render_block', 'test_filter', 10, 3);`